# How do we programatically add data from datagrid to list?

Tags: c#, .net, list, datagrid

I have the following code, but the list is not fetching the exact values from datagrid.

```
public List<double[]> ExtractGridData(DataGridView grid)
    {
        int numCols = grid.Columns.Count;
        List<double[]> list = new List<double[]>();

            double[] cellsData = new double[numCols];
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in grid.SelectedCells)
            {
                if (cell.Value != null)
                    cellsData[cell.RowIndex] = Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value);
                    list.Add(cellsData);
            }

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: You want To retrive the Entire Grid data or The Data in selected Cells/Rows

Answer (score 0):

I *think* all you need to do is move:

```
double[] cellsData = new double[numCols];
```

to within the start of your loop.  At the moment, your using the same instance of the array every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

try this Code as Extract data from Grid for a Specific column

```
 public List<double> ExtractGridData(DataGridView grid)
    {
        int numCols = grid.Columns.Count;
        List<double> list = new List<double>();
        int i = 0;
        double[] cellsData = new double[numCols];
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.SelectedRows)
        {
            if(row.Cells[2].Value != null)
            {
            string value = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();// third columnn of Grid as            //Example



            list.Add(Convert.ToDouble(value));
            }  


        }


        return list;
    }
```